# AJAX POST variable not being read by php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Why would this not work for me ? It's an AJAX POST request to a php script, the script has been tested and works fine with fixed variables.

The request is as follows

```
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data:{serial:id},
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){}
```

My php is

```
    <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
echo 'POSTed'; 
 } //to test post

$account = $_POST['serial'];
```

....etc

which is followed my a MySQL request.

And from my console everything looks fine, except I get " Undefined index: serial" as my response. I have tried constructing my POST variables many different ways. It come from source which when viewed shows the correct variable.

```
var id =  localStorage.userAccount;
```

Comment: what value you see in firebug console while posting the data.
Check the POST tab and let me know what is displays for the ajax request. you might be missing something there

Comment: why are you setting contentType as `application/json` ?

Comment: or why don't you `var_dump($_POST)` and check what is received.

Comment: Add an `alert()` or `console.log` before the ajax call to see the value of `serial`

Comment: what it prints on server if you write <?print_r($_POST);?>

Comment: actually using chrome but im getting "serial=8" as Requested Payload, Everything else seems OK to me but I am new to debugging through a browser.

Comment: instead of `echo "POSTED"` use `var_dump($_POST)` and check the output.

Comment: the var_dump shows a response of "array(0) {}" ? I presume I am not constructing the datastring properly ?

Comment: do you really have "id" ? what is id?
var id= $('div').val();

Comment: id comes from local starage and shows on console and through alert() so I presume it is set correctly. This has me puzzled if I'm honest.

Comment: Ok, silly shot in the dark - try a space between "serial" and "id", i.e. `data:{serial: id},`

Comment: Thanks to all for the help, some of the advice here will help me debug my php better in future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need to add `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",` in `jquery.ajax`. just remove it and then try.

Comment: I actually have a json encoded response in the full script, the ('Content-type: application/json'); is actually just something I had in there from experimenting with PhoneGap, sorry about that.

Comment: That was it, never would have though of removing it as it worked with other requests, appreciate the help, Thanks

Comment: I got problem while posting my custom parameters in data part and using following ajax parameters `processData: false,              contentType: false ` SO I removed that 2 parameters and I got POST data!!! For knowledge only. Thanks!